# How can I use different computational operations to get the results of two numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to get the results of two different numbers using "+","-", and mod"%" operators. However, I am running into trouble in coding it. I am using a textfile of numbers that look like this: 57854879876656543423468 and 654589876578097433579, to code this. Please help! I don't know where to add or how to go about doing it.
edit: thank you soooo much!!

Comment: You should really consider using an array that can already change capacity automatically: std::vector   Or are you constrained by your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I’m constrained by requirements

Comment: Here is how you could write an add function the old fashioned way working right to left using a carry: https://onlinegdb.com/Z9w5o0YaZ

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you need to:

- Write 3 functions (add, sub, mod). Ideally you should place them between existing print_number() and main() functions.
- Each of these functions will work with 3 numbers (2 operands and one result). Since your numbers are stored as pairs of values (a pointer to the first digit and a number of digits), these functions will work with 6 parameters. This is how the declaration of "add" can look like:

```
void add(short * a, const size_t digits_in_a, short * b, const size_t digits_in_b, short * c, size_t& digits_in_c) {
    // Here you add b and c digit by digit and store the result in c. 
}
```

- The add function will work the same way like kids add numbers in elementary school - in a loop, digit by digit, and if the result of adding two digits is greater than 10, you carry 1 to the next iteration and subtract 10 from the current partial result. What you must not forget is increasing capacity of your result (c) in every iteration by calling function increase_capacity(c, digits_in_c).
- The sub function is similar
- In mod function you can probably call sub(), until the remainder is negative, if you're not required to iplement division.
- You'll call your functions in the main() function, between lines

```
print_number(p_number2, ...);
```

and

```
delete[] p_number1;
```

- Before calling your functions, you'll need to create storage for your results, for example:

```
size_t digits_in_result1 = 0, digits_in_result2 = 0, digits_in_result3 = 0;
short * p_result1 = new short[0];
short * p_result2 = new short[0];
short * p_result3 = new short[0];
```

- You'll probably want to print results by calling print_number().
- Do not forget to delete results at the end.